# Iterate through a vector

Tags: c++, iteration

I have a class as follow:

```
class Descriptor
{

public:

float   xi, yi;     
vector<double>  fv;         
Descriptor()
{
}

Descriptor(float x, float y, vector<double> const& f)
{
    xi = x;
    yi = y;
    fv = f;
}
};
```

also I have a vector of Descriptor like this:`vector<Descriptor> keypoint;`

Now I want to print the elements of the keypoint using iterators considering fv is a vector of double.

I wrote this code

```
vector<Descriptor>::iterator it;

for(it=keypoint.begin();it!=keypoint.end();it++){
    cout<<it->xi <<"---"<<it->yi<<endl; 
    double* f = it->fv.data();
    for(int i=0; i<it->fv.size();i++){
        cout<<*f<<endl;
        f++;
    }
}
```

but if I have e.g xi=3 and yi=4 and a fv=[5 6 7]
it prints fv three times like this: 3 4 5 6 7 5 6 7 5 6 7
please help me how to correct it...

Comment: Show the actual code, the smallest program you can write that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem. Since `"---"` does not appear anywhere in your sample output, the output is not from the code snippet you've shown.

Comment: The code you've posted, while a bit weird in its use of pointer arithmetic, should work as expected ([demonstration](http://ideone.com/fpjxVp)). Presumably, the vector doesn't contain what you think it does. Could you post some code (preferably, a small, complete program) to show how you're populating the vector before getting this output?

Comment: Your code looks correct, I would prefer `for(int i=0; i <it->fv.size();i++){cout<<it->fv[i] ... ` instead of your pointer on a double.

Comment: Dear Mike, please send me your email address to send you me code.

Comment: @user2671120: If you want an answer, then update the question to include code that demonstrates the problem. There's no point sending it to me; I'm not a freelance debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, do you have any test code that demonstrates the problem?  And why are you using `f`?  It doesn't seem to be necessary with the loop you are using anyway.  I'd recommend using

```
vector<Descriptor>::iterator it;

for(it = keypoint.begin(); it != keypoint.end(); it++){
    cout << it->xi << "---" << it->yi <<endl; 
    for(int i = 0; i < it->fv.size(); i++){
        cout << it->fv[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I apply your code as well but I got the same output:                                                 3---4   5 6 7 5 6 7 5 6 7

Comment: Then I would recommend posting exactly what your input is, then someone can re-create the scenario and possibly tell you what's wrong

Comment: Dear sedavidw, please send me your email to send you my code.

Comment: @user2671120 You don't need my email, just post it in your question